# Accessing micronaut config from another library

Tags: java, micronaut, graalvm

I'm experimenting with micronaut and graal and have an issue I can't resolve.

I've created 2 projects from this example: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java.html, called appA and appB with the following changes.

- appA has application-a.yml configuration
- appB has application-b.yml config file.

Both libraries successfully loads their configs when compiled natively (or started with java).

Now I include the appA as dependency of the appB and it seems I can't load application-a.yaml for appB usage when it compiled natively. (starting it with Java works).

```
env MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES=classpath:application-a.yml,classpath:application-b.yml  ./build/native/nativeCompile/appB
```

produces **Error starting Micronaut server: Failed to read configuration file: classpath:application-a.yml**

Classloader returns null is getResourceAsStream()

I tried:

- use MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES env
- set "a" environment in appB context builder
- add application-a.yml to appA native resources configuration file ->  "pattern": ".*/application-a.yml"
- add application-a.yml to appB native resources configuration file  ->  "pattern": ".*/application-a.yml"

All my attempts has failed. Micronaut loads configuration when started with Java and fails in native-image.

I suspect, that application-a.yml from appA is not a "classpath" for appB. Are there any options to overcome this?